# PDO let database stay open, or open and close when needed?

Tags: php, pdo

I have just discovered PDO and I'm very excited about it, but I have read a few tutorials on how to implement it, and they show me different ways of doing it.

So now I'm confused which way is the best.

example 1: open database once.

```
  include("host.php"); //including the database connection
  //random PDO mysql stuff here
```

Example 2: open close the database when needed:

```
try {
$dbh = new PDO(mysql stuff);
$sql = "mysql stuff";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
    {
    echo $row['something'];
    }

/*** close the database connection ***/
$dbh = null;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Which is best? I would think example 2 is best, but there much more code than example 1.

Comment: Only close the DB handle if you know you're done with it, or have made so many mods to MySQL variables/settings that it'd be easier to start with a new clean handle rather than undo all the changes.

Comment: so if i have 7 diffrent mysql querys example 2 would be best ?

Comment: no. example 1 would be. no point in closing the connection if you're just going to need it again. it'd be like driving to the store, buying milk, driving home, go to the store again, get bread, drive home, etc... pointless roundtrips.

Comment: i get your point, that would really be stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, there is significant time spent/lost when connecting, and you want to do it only once. Do not go closing a connection you need later on, it will only slow things down. You *may* consider closing a connection sooner if you are reaching the maximum connections limit, but that's more a hint you should scale up then a permanent solution IMHO.